# Comments on migrated question no longer relevant

Tags: support

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/273904/email-utopia-cross-platform-inc-mobile-encryption-signing-threading-accoun) of mine was migrated from StackOverflow to SuperUser. The comments on it are no longer relevant. Can they be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, comments deleted as per your request.  In the future, **flag your question** and ask for the comments to be deleted, instead of a Meta question.

Comment: Er, I'll try to remember. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: @sampa, you can also flag comments as noise if you spot these anywhere around the site.